# my procedure with cursor in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it.
I need to create a procedure with cursor to insert into Vizite: dataora (i need a function), Medici_Idm,Pacienti_Idm,Cabinete_Idm from temporary table.My procedure doesn't work, i also use for select tables: Medici, Pacineti,Cabinete to extract id.

Table 1:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Vizite (
        Idv INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        DataOra DATETIME,
        Medici_Idm  INT NOT NULL,
        Pacienti_Idp INT NOT NULL,
        Cabinete_Idc INT NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (Medici_Idm) REFERENCES Medici(Idm),
        FOREIGN KEY (Pacienti_Idp) REFERENCES Pacienti(Idp),
        FOREIGN KEY (Cabinete_Idc) REFERENCES Cabinete(Idc)
        ) Engine=INNODB;
```

Table 2:

```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TempVizite (
        Idt INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        DataVizita VARCHAR(250),
        OraIntrare TIME,
        NumePacient VARCHAR(250),
        PrenumePacient VARCHAR(250),
        NumeMedic VARCHAR(250),
        PrenumeMedic VARCHAR(250),
        Cabinet VARCHAR (250));
```

the procedure:

```
DELIMITER /
CREATE PROCEDURE VARIANTA3()
BEGIN
    DECLARE M_I,P_I,C_I VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE I_V INT;
    DECLARE D DATE;
    DECLARE O TIME;


    DECLARE CURS1 CURSOR FOR                -- declaram cursorul
        SELECT IDT,DATAVIZITA,ORAINTRARE,NUMEMEDIC,NUMEPACIENT,CABINET FROM TEMPVIZITE;
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR 1329 BEGIN END;    -- declaram handler specific erorii de terminarea cursorului


    OPEN CURS1; 
    BUCLA: LOOP
        FETCH CURS1 INTO M_I,P_I,C_I,I_V,D,O;
        INSERT IGNORE INTO  VIZITE VALUES(I_V,@DATAORA,M_I,P_I,C_I);
        SELECT TIMESTAMP(DATAVIZITA,ORAINTRARE) INTO @DATAORA;
        SELECT IDM FROM MEDICI WHERE NUME = NUMEMEDIC INTO M_I;
        SELECT IDP FROM PACIENTI WHERE NUME = NUMEPACIENT INTO P_I;
        SELECT IDC FROM CABINETE WHERE NUME = CABIENT INTO C_I;

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE CURS1;
END /
DELIMITER ;
```